# Delete Customer from Admin Panel in Magento-2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1, customer

When i delete customer from admin panel of Magento-2.1.12.Any problem is occur in Magento-2.1.12????

Comment: Can you please add error text or screenshot to get a clear idea.

Comment: Please redefine your question. Is your question: 'Is there a chance that a problem can occur when deleting a customer from the admin panel?' or is it 'I have a problem when deleting a customer in the admin panel'. If it is the last question, please specify any errors. This way we cannot help you.

Comment: I am just asking,if i delete any customer from admin panel.This will not create any issue.I an right or not?

Comment: It will not create any problem.

Comment: And one thing more,can i delete a order ?

Comment: I have some orders,which are not open it show error Product does not exist.